# php how to divide a list of while loop result

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

PHP:

```
function get_t_wrinkle_rel(){

        global $mysqli;
        $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_wrinkle_rel ORDER BY t_wrinkle_name ASC");

        while ($r = $q->fetch_array()) :

            echo '<p><input type="checkbox"' . $r['t_wrinkle_name'] . '</p>';

        endwhile;

    }
```

RESULT:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Crows feet">Crows feet
<input type="checkbox" value="Frown lines" >Frown lines
<input type="checkbox" value="Lip augmentation">Lip augmentation
<input type="checkbox" value="Lip lines">Lip lines
<input type="checkbox" value="Marionette lines">Marionette lines
```

i want the result:

```
**LEFT**                                      **RIGHT**
<input type="checkbox">Crows feet |<input type="checkbox" >Lip lines
<input type="checkbox">Frown lines | <input type="checkbox">Marionette lines
<input type="checkbox"">Lip augmentation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not alternate a class on each second input that suggests clearing a float or something similar if you are not floating the inputs? Something along the lines of:

```
function get_t_wrinkle_rel(){
        global $mysqli;
        $flag = 1;
        $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_wrinkle_rel ORDER BY t_wrinkle_name ASC");
        while ($r = $q->fetch_array()) :
            if ($flag = 1) {
                $orientate=left;$flag=0;
            } else {
                $orientate=right;$flag=1;
            }
            echo '<p><input class="' . $orientate .  '"type="checkbox"' . $r['t_wrinkle_name'] . '</p>';
        endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Code is slightly long-winded for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($left = $q->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<input...>' . $left['...'];
    if ($right = $q->fetch_array()) {
        echo '| <input...>' . $right['...'];
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way should fill the left column in order then the right column, keeping the order you want to achieve. I don't have access to your database so I can't test this, but it should do the job.

```
function get_t_wrinkle_rel(){
    global $mysqli;
    $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_wrinkle_rel ORDER BY t_wrinkle_name ASC");

    $mid    = floor($q->num_rows/2);    // Get halfway point
    $count  = 0;
    $array  = array();
    while($r = $q->fetch_array()){
        $string = '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$r['t_wrinkle_name'].'" />'.$r['t_wrinkle_name'];
        if($count <= $mid){
            // Left column
            $array[$count]  = $string;
        } else {
            // Right column
            $array[$count-$mid] .= '|'.$string;

        }
        $count++;
    }

// Make single string
echo implode('', $array);
}
```

However I would recommend using the idea **biscuitstack** suggested, using CSS to position it the way you want, rather than doing it programatically. It's always better to try to keep presentation separate from the logic wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flag that increments everytime and

```
<input type="checkbox"' . $r['t_wrinkle_name'] . 
if flag % 2 == 0 then echo '<br />'
```

Or something like that.